# Advice needed on database design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am new to database designing. In my case I have to generate lot many keys per user per product. So, I have two options -

1. Create one table with product_id and key for all the users, or
2. Create a separate table for each user

In the former case I will have a single table but querying might take more time as all the entries are in the same table for all the users.
 In the later case queries might return the result faster but more tables and if users cross 100 or more than it means lot of tables.

Comment: _Always_ create one table; a database is designed to query data quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely do not create a table for each user.  if you create a single table for all users you can use relational database design and add specific information pertaining to each user like address or employee information and use the primary key from the users table as a foreign key.  and there will not be any noticeable lag.  And maintenance will be  whole lot easier

Answer (score 1):

if you want to build relation between your user and product then make table like below

```
user_product [table name]

id [Primary Key] 
user_id [Reference key of user table]
product_id [Reference key of product table]
key
```

This is your table schema You must use.

if you generate each table then this will take more complex for database and relation management. So, just use above row base format.

if that helpful then let me know.

Thanks

Comment: You don't even need the id primary key.  Using (user_id, product_id) as primary key should work just as well, and makes sure the combination is unique (instead of having to define a separate unique key). You _do_ want to add an extra index on product_id, though, since that's not indexed on its own by default.

Comment: @JigarChaudhary Thanks for the reply, I only needed an advice, I already have the schema.